# How can i implement tap and hold feature

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I wanted to implement a Tap and Hold feature on windows phone 8 to display a few settings options. Can anyone guide me how to perform this task ?

Comment: Any effort so far? I guess not.

Comment: I just want a direction that how can i do this i am unable to understand how to start learning this

Comment: <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
   <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" >
     <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Edit" Header="Edit" />
     <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Delete"  Header="Delete" />
   </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>  I have completed my code thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a ContextMenu for the element you are interested in. It's included in the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanx for your guidance i am now able to implement this functionality in my application